# If $|n|< b^m$ then $|n|= \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} x_i b^i$ (representation of a number in terms of radix/ base $b$)

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

> Let $b$ denote the radix (=base), suppose that for some $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $m \in \mathbb N$ we know that:
>   $|n|< b^m$ then prove that $$|n|= \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} x_ib ^i$$
>   Where $x_i \in \{0, 1 ,2 ,3 , 4 \dots b-1 \}$.

Basically this says that if we know that a given number is smaller than some power of the radix, then it must have a representation using the lower powers.

Example:
 If $|n|< 2^{10}$  then we know this number has some binary representation using at most 9 bits. Give or take a minus sign.

How do we prove this?

I feel this is a job for **the Euclidean division algorithm**, but not sure how to formulate this. Could I get some help with the steps?

Comment: 1. Prove that $|n|$ can be "written" in base $b$, i.e. $|n|=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k x_i b^i$. 2. Assume $k>m-1$ and see if you obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good breakdown, I will try the first step.

Comment: If $n=0$ we are done with all $x_k$ zero; assume $n \ne 0$ and then pick $k$ (necessarily $k<m$) s.t. $b^k \le |n| < b^{k+1}$, then there is unique $0 < x_k <b, x_kb^k \le |n| < (x_k+1)b^k$ and let $0 \le n_1=|n|-x_kb^k < b^k$. Repeat...

Comment: I got stuck at the step "then there is a unique $0 < x_k < b$, and then I also do not see how $b^k  \leq |n| < b^{k+1} \implies  x_ k b^k \leq |n| < (x_k +1)b^k$.

Comment: I understand that you repeat the procedure until you get some 
$ 0 \leq n_k < b$  which means that for every step of the way you get in a sense some  "digit" in your representation in terms of the radix $b$, that is, iteratively you obtain:
$$ |n| = \sum_{i=0}^k x_i b^i$$
Where you started with $b^{k+1}$ as an upper bound (rather than $b^k$)

I also suppose that necessarily $k+1 \leq m$..

Comment: The second step would be to prove that $k>m-1$ gives a contradiction, such that indeed we must have that $k \leq m-1 \implies k+1 \leq m$. If $k+1$ is really less than $m$, we simply pad it with zeros to make it of length $m$. Problem solved. The only step that then remains is to prove that the former leads to a contradiction.